# Custom toolbar hide problem with Firefox

Tags: firefox, toolbar

I have created a couple of custom toolbars in Firefox, I hide them and closed Firefox. When I open up Firefox next time, all custom toolbars are visible. Why Firefox is not remembering hide settings of custom toolbars, it do remember hide settings for other toolbars like Yahoo or Google toolbar.

How I can make them hidden by default?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you have found the answer for this question. So here is the answer for new firefox extensions' developers: you should use document.persist() function to save the state of the attributes.

So if you want to save your toolbar's collapsed attrubute value (say your toolbar's ID is "samplebar") you should write this:

```
document.persist("samplebar", "collapsed")
```

Second argument is the attribute name you want to be saved.